# Message-Sending App with Pre-defined Buttons

Tags: android, button, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

my question is about my message sending app. I am trying to send a message on the press of a button, but I am stuck on something. I looked at a tutorial and followed it, and managed to change the code to  my own function, but I can't figure out how to send the message on the click of the button (ex. When I press the red button, I have to press the "send" button to actually send the message. I want to send the message after just pressing the red button).

Ideally I want to implement both into my program, but it's taking longer than I thought, so I'm just sticking to my original goal. Can anyone see where I should change my code?

```
package app.real_time_chat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by David on 5/01/2017
 */
public class Chat_Room  extends AppCompatActivity{

private Button btn_send_msg;
private Button button_msg;
private EditText input_msg;
private TextView chat_conversation;

private String user_name,room_name;
private DatabaseReference root ;
private String temp_key;
private String greeting;                                                            
//for displaying button messages

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat_room);


    button_msg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_red);
    button_msg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            greeting = "It's Red" ;                                                 
//for displaying red color

        }});

    button_msg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_blue);
    button_msg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            greeting = "It's Blue" ;                                                  //for displaying blue color

        }});

    button_msg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_green);
    button_msg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            greeting = "It's Green" ;                                                  
//for displaying green color

        }});

    button_msg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_yellow);
    button_msg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            greeting = "It's Yellow" ;                                                  //for displaying yellow color

        }});

    btn_send_msg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

//      btn_send_msg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);                               


    input_msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg_input);
    chat_conversation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    user_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name").toString();                //converts username to string to display to screen
    room_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("room_name").toString();                //converts room name to string to display to screen
    setTitle(" Room - "+room_name);                                                 //displays pre-set room name to top of app page

    root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(room_name);

    btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            temp_key = root.push().getKey();
            root.updateChildren(map);

            DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
            Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map2.put("name",user_name);
            map2.put("msg",greeting);
 //             map2.put("msg",input_msg.getText().toString());                           



            message_root.updateChildren(map2);
        }
    });

    root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

private String chat_msg,chat_user_name;

private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()){

           chat_msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
        chat_user_name = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();

        chat_conversation.append(chat_user_name +" : "+chat_msg +" \n");
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just add call on click to the methods like

```
button_msg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            greeting = "It's Yellow" ;                                                  //for displaying yellow color
           btn_send_msg.callOnClick();
        }});
```

if you want to do both you should do something like this and make a new method

add

```
private void sendMessage(String message)
{
     Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            temp_key = root.push().getKey();
            root.updateChildren(map);

            DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
            Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map2.put("name",user_name);
            map2.put("msg",message);
 //             map2.put("msg",input_msg.getText().toString());                           



            message_root.updateChildren(map2);
}
```

then the buttons should be like 
    button_msg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_red);
    button_msg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            sendMessage("It's Red");                                                 
//for displaying red color

        }});
```

and the send button that sends input would be

```
btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            sendMessage(input_msg.getText().toString());                           
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry for my noob question, but how is the program going to distinguish between the buttons? Do I make conditional statements? (for the 4 buttons, there are 4 greetings, so do I make a condition for each button?)

Comment: do you need to? just put btn_send_msg.callOnClick(); in each listener. the greeting is set by each one, so send listener just adds map2.put("msg",greeting);   and it should be fine

Comment: Oh my, you are a genius!! It works perfectly now. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Btw just a quick side-question. Would the code need to be re-vamped to allow for both button and input-messaging? This was originally a input-messaging code, but now it can only be one or another (I tried to implement both, but when I do only the input-message is displayed, not the button messages)

Comment: @davvy take a look now

Comment: Omg, you are really smart. I wish I could upvote you 100 times. Thank you again for the answers!!